# COM Class on a destination machine

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6

I followed this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248 tutorial to make a .NET COM class for my vb6 project to be able to access. I added it through references but what it adds is the testproj.tlb file and not the testproj.dll. It works fine on my development machine.

However I took the compiled .exe and made a setup for it through vs6 tools. Included the reference for it. Including my testproj.tlb installed it on the host machine and got the error `Run Time error '429' ActiveX component can't create object`

Shouldn't the installer include the necessary references for this to run on a destination machine? The .exe is a very simple one so the only object that is being declared is the COM Class. How do i get my COM class to work on a destination machine?

Comment: Your component did not get registered properly.  Which isn't much of a mystery, "VS6 tools" cannot do this correctly since it knows beans about Regasm.exe or the way that .NET assemblies need to be registered.

Comment: Thanks yeah i put the installer inside a .net setup project and added the dependencies and it works now. However when i add the .tlb and the .dll gets added the .dll needs to make sure it is changed to vsdrfCOM in register property. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i put the installer inside a .net setup project and added the dependencies and it works now. However when i add the .tlb and the .dll gets added the .dll needs to make sure it is changed to vsdrfCOM in register property